# two column latex line number for revtex4-1

Tags: two-column, lineno

1. I want to move the line numbers of right column to the right side of column
   (I already tried switch and columnwise line numbers).
2. I need line numbers for figure and table captions

This is a minimal sample

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{No problem}
\maketitle
\linenumbers
\blindtext[15]
\end{document}
```